# Foreign key constraint when deleting entity with many to many relationship

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, h2

I have two entities:

```
  @Data
  @Entity
  @Table(name = "tags")
  public static class Tag {
    public abstract class BaseEntity extends AutoUpdatable {
      @Id
      @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
      private UUID id;

      @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "tags")
      private List<Article> articles;
  }

  @Data
  @Entity
  @Table(name = "articles")
  public static class Article {
    @Id
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private UUID id;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name = "articles_tags",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "article_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id")
    )
    private List<Tag> tags;
  }
```

All I need it's when deleting tag - remove it also from collections of tag in article entity.
I need to implement it via spring data jpa.
I use the latest version of spring boot and h2 database.

Is it a elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only do it on delete you can use [`CascadeType.REMOVE`](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/hibernate/hibernate-cascadetype-remove-example/) parameter in your relationship mapping:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
@JoinTable(
    name = "articles_tags",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "article_id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id")
)
private List<Tag> tags;
```

However this can result in [a number of DELETE statements](https://thoughts-on-java.org/avoid-cascadetype-delete-many-assocations/) which might not be optimal.